# Rotation makes UIImageView moves up -iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, rotation, cgaffinetransform

I am using the following code to rotate my image view and it is working fine..but whenever I change the view and go back. my image view moves up and eventually goes off the screen.. Any ideas why? Thanks..

```
self.anchorImage.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0,0.0);

CGAffineTransform cgaRotateHr = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1);
[self.imageView setTransform:cgaRotateHr];
```

Comment: Do you at any point (probably when the view appears) change/set the position of that view?

Comment: one solution would be to store the center of the self.imageView and set it back whenever you are coming back to the view...but thats definitley not an ideal solution..

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist no. i have a few more image views and none of them has the same problem. if I remove [self.imageView setTransform:cgaRotateHr]; then everything is still fine..